# Android in Eclipse, Merge / Include nested XML non-layout resources

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, include

I have an XML index in the res/xml/ folder, and I would like it to include other xml files, so that when I parse R.xml.index, all the files are merged into a single resource.

I tried to adapt the [include layout trick](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) to xml parsing, so my `index.xml` looks like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Index xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Sheet>
    <include xml="o_2sq_m.xml"/>
    <include xml="o_2sq_r.xml"/>
</Sheet>
<Sheet>
    <include xml="o_sq_tr_m.xml"/>
    <include xml="o_sq_tr_r.xml"/>
</Sheet>
</Index>
```

and the file `o_2sq_m.xml`, which is in the same folder as index.xml, looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Challenge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Dimensions maxX="512" maxY="342" />
<Point id="1" x="94" y="101" color="0x00000000" />
...
</Challenge>
```

But when I parse index.xml with and [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html), I see in the debugger that it parses the include tags without having them unrolled, i.e. it does not access the tree of the file o_2sq_m.xml

What should I do to have android include the files within one other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not doing too much XML import (such as at create time), you could use [`getResources().getIdentifier()`](http://steven.bitsetters.com/2007/11/27/accessing-android-resources-by-name-at-runtime/), which for an index like that (remove the `.xml` in the attribute)

```
<Index xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Sheet>
    <include customAttr="o_2sq_m"/> ...
</Sheet>
```

and given that your file to be included is named `o_2sq_m.xml`, you could use the following code:

```
switch(tag) {
case "include" :
   String xmlid = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "customAttr");
   Int xmlIncludedId = res.getIdentifier(xmlid, "xml", getPackageName());
   if(xmlIncludedId != 0) {
     // Here the xmlIncludedId can be used to import other XML files.
     // E.g. getResources().getXml(xmlIncludedId) returns an XmlResourceParser
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The  tag is used for layouts not for any xml file. If you use it for layout, the layout inflater will replace it with the corresponding file when needed. In a normal xml it will be considered a tag like any other. I do not think it's possible to do what you want.